# 22.04 has so much screen tearing in Chrome it's almost unusable

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 22.04, google-chrome, tearing

I've always had minor screen tearing problems in Ubuntu 20.04 and before, with both ATI and nvidia cards.   Mostly in Chrome and Zoom and a few other apps.  Usually only after running the X server for weeks, and restarting Chrome fixed it for a while so I could handle it.

But now after upgrade to 22.04 it's off the charts.  Chrome is still the worst culprit, but it happens immediately after boot now, and strongly, and restarting Chrome doesn't work.

Yes, I have set "Force Full Composition Pipeline" which I just learned about (maybe it would have fixed things in 20.04.)  I have made sure I have the latest Nvidia driver 525.60.11, and kernel5.15.0-58-generic.    I have 55 gigs of free ram.    All packages are up to date in apt.

So what other tricks can I do, or what driver should I try to revert to?

Comment: Try switching GPUs with:   __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia google-chrome

Comment: Sorry, where would I put this config?

Comment: That example is a one-off on the command line, just before the program to be run.  You can put those variables into your .profile if you want them permanent.  When running xorg, the xrandr --listproviders will output the nvidia and other (intel) GPU. The example assumes the offload defaults to 0, the modesetting, Intel GPU, so that gets switched.

Comment: Ah, so environment variables.   No other GPU for me, it's a Ryzen 7 with an nvidia graphics card.     Only one provider.   I also upgraded nvidia proprietary driver to 525 which didn't happen automatically in the upgrade, and it's slightly better but still no joy.

Comment: Well, my problem with Chrome is fixable by disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome, but that's hardly the desired solution, and no doubt problems will emerge in other programs, so it would be nice to find the permanent solution - and why the upgrade to 22.04 made it so much worse.